# Ensure that only required data stay and outdated are removed

Tags: salt-stack

We use salt to bootstrap our web server. We host multiple different domains. I create a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` for each of our domains. Then I symlink it to `sites-enabled`.

The problem is that if I move the domain to different server, the link from `sites-enabled` is not removed.  If I change the domain name and keep the data in place - then I have old.domain.com and new.domain.com vhost files. I expect to end up with only new.domain.com in `sites-enabled`, but both files are there and the working domain depends on alphabet (I guess) - which of the vhosts is loaded first.

I have the domains stored in pillars and generate the vhosts like:

```
{%- for site in pillar.sites %}
/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ site.name }}:
  file:
  - managed
  - source: salt://apache/conf/sites/site
  - template: jinja
  - require: 
    - file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    - cmd: apache_rewrite_enable
  - defaults:
    site_name: "{{ site.name }}"
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{{ site.name }}:
  file.symlink:
  - target: /etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ site.name }}
  - require:
    - file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ site.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to make sure that only the vhosts listed in pillars stay after highstate. I thought about emptying the folder first, but that feels dangerous as the highstate may fail mid-air and I would be left withou any vhosts - crippling all the other domains - just because I tried to add one.

Is there a way to enforce something like: "remove everything that was not present in this highstate run"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that Salt doesn't do anything you don't specify.  It would be too hard (and quite dangerous) to try to automatically manage a whole server by default.  So `file.managed` and `file.symlink` just make sure that their target files and symlinks are present and in the correct state -- they can't afford to worry about other files.

You have a couple of options.  The first is to clean the directory at the beginning of each highstate.  Like you mentioned, this is not ideal, because it's a bit dangerous (and if a highstate fails, none of your sites will work).

The better option would be to put *all* of your sites in each minion's pillar:  some would go under the 'sites' key in pillar, and the rest might go under the 'disabled' key in pillar.  Then you could use the `file.absent` state to make sure each of the 'disabled' site-files is absent.  (as well as the symlink for those files)

Then when you move a domain from host to host, rather than just removing that domain from the pillar of the previous minion, you would actually move it from the 'sites' key to the 'disabled' key.  Then you'd be guaranteed that that site would be gone.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's a great idea. I actually have all sites in one file with key "worker" specifying the server where it's located. And with simple if in the SLS file checking if the worker FQDN == value of the worker key. I can easily add file.absent into the elif part of the condition.  Thank you very much!